Does btrfs RAID5 or RAID6 have benefits over btrfs on RAID10?
From what I understand, btrfs is implementing RAID 5 and 6 support after having had RAID 0, 1 and 10 support stable for quite a while now.
btrfs already has check-summing and background scrubbing. What benefit does RAID 5 or RAID 6 provide over btrfs on RAID10?

I don't recommend to use RAID5/6 in any kind of form. It's only advantage is that it just need 1/3 disk space for having redundancy (RAID1 needs 1/2 disk space), but its most and biggest disadvantage is, that it's slow as hell and that rebuilding a drive also has a tendency to overuse the older working drives, resulting in a destruction of the array, with lost of all data. If you really intend to use BTRFS RAID5/6 you must use an UPS, otherwise you have a very good chance to doom all your data.

What benefit does RAID 5 or RAID 6 provide over btrfs on RAID10? None. Also, btfrs has had RAID5/6 for several years. There is a question on SuperUser about RAID5 on btfrs from 2018. What you may be referring to are the remediation of outstanding defects on RAID 5/6 implementation on btfrs from 2020, the reputation damage due to that type of defect, and the time required (months to years) to accept the remediation. https://lore.kernel.org/linux-btrfs/20200627030614.GW10769@hungrycats.org/

Parity style redundancy can be more space efficient than mirroring, but parity is more complex. Especially with many disks a raid6 would have more usable capacity than a raid1.
As a file system for experimenting with fancy features including volume management, a parity option seems obvious.  Unfortunately, btrfs raid5 or 6 are more likely than other profiles to cause interesting problems of the kind you might need file system support. As of 2024, man 5 btrfs regarding raid56

There are some implementation and design deficiencies that make it unreliable for some corner cases and the feature should not be used in production, only for evaluation or testing. The power failure safety for metadata with RAID56 is not 100%.

Metadata must be raid1 or raid1c3. Scrub on the entire array at once can cause ruinous performance issues. Must scrub after unclean shutdown. Degraded arrays can be tricky to repair.  See mailing list thread How to use btrfs raid5 successfully(ish)  or this Ars Technica review. Although both posts are a few years old, so some bugs may have been fixed since.
btrfs features, scrubs, snapshots, might be valuable enough to you to use it anyway.  And ways exist to do so without using btrfs' parity implementation:

btrfs raid10
btrfs single on top of a different array hardware or software (md, lvm)
btrfs single on top of just one physical disk

